# How to Retrieve the table same as excel table into an email using ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, loop

How to output excel table as table into an email using amp script code? but each week the number of products I feature could change up or down, how could I build the email so that it can pull in each row and adapt to more or less products?

so i have used the below code but i can get only one value as below:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("Product")   
set @lookupValue = "Tylenol"  
set @numRowsToReturn = 0  
set @rows = LookupRows("ProductsDE","Product",@lookupValue)  
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then
]%%


<table border="1">
<tr >
<td>Product</td>
<td> Size </td>
<td> Price </td>
<td> Normal Price </td>
<td> PCT </td>
</tr>
%%[
  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @Product, @Size
    set @row = row(@rows,@i)
    set @Product = field(@row,"Product")
    set @Size = field(@row,"Size")
 set @Price = field(@row,"Price")
 set @Normal_Price = field(@row,"Normal_Price")
 set @PCT = field(@row,"Percent_Discount")

    ]%%
<tr >
<td> %%=v(@Product)=%%</td>
<td>  %%=v(@Size)=%% </td>
<td>  %%=v(@Price)=%% </td>
<td>  %%=v(@Normal_Price)=%% </td>
<td> %%=v(@PCT)=%% </td>
</tr>

    %%[ 
  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

</table>

%%[ endif ]%%
```

I GOT THE OUTPUT AS BELOW

[image]

But i need to get the output as below:
[image]

Comment: your lookuprows is only returning one item, you need to evaluate your criteria on the lookup

Answer (score 1):

the way lookupRows works is that it uses an "equals" operator.

```
set @rows = LookupRows("ProductsDE","Product",@lookupValue)
```

translates to "construct a (virtual) table from all rows in "ProductsDE" where column "Product" *equals* @lookupValue", in your case, "Tylenol".

Hence your virtual table has only one row, leading to your result.

What you need is a column where all relevant rows have the same value, so  you can use that for your *equals* comparison.

Looking at your data, you don't have one. Your rows have nothing in common.

So: Build one. Add a column that sets a defaultValue for all (relevant, if it is only a subset) rows, now all rows have something in common.

Then you can use that column in your lookupRows.
Something like:

```
set @rows = LookupRows("ProductsDE","commonRowMarker","true")
```

Keep in mind the built-in limit for how many rows your virtual table can have though, lookuprows retrieves a max of **2000** rows. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/lookuprows.html